# Trouble with reading a dictionary file

Tags: python-3.x

Hi my assignment is to read the company names and the shorten names of the companies.

This file with tickers below is given:

ticker_symbol.txt

```
YAHOO:YHOO
GOOGLE INC:GOOG
Harley-Davidson:HOG
Yamana Gold:AUY
Sotheby's:BID
inBev:BUD
```

So I need to make 3 functions: def tickers_to_dict(filename), def name_to_symbol(name, ticker_dict) and def symbol_to_name(symbol, ticker_dict).

In the function tickers_to_dict(filename), I need to convert the text file into a dictionary and return it which I have done succesfully.

In the functions def name_to_symbol(name, ticker_dict) and def symbol_to_name(symbol, ticker_dict), I need to find the ticker symbol in the dictionary by the input of the company name and the reverse. (by a input of a ticker symbol it needs to find the company name). But I dont know how to solve this two functions. Can someone help me? So far I have this:

```
def tickers_to_dict():
    ticker_dict = {}
    bestand = open('ticker_symbol.txt', 'r')
    tickers = bestand.readlines()
    for line in tickers:
        k, v = line.split(':')
        ticker_dict[k] = v
    return (ticker_dict)

print(tickers_to_dict())

def name_to_symbol(name, ticker_dict):
```

output needs to be like this:

```
Enter Company name: YAHOO
Ticker symbol: YHOO
 
Enter Ticker symbol: BUD
Company name: inBev
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this ist what you were looking for but here you go:

```
def name_to_symbol(mydict):
    given_input = input("Enter company name: ")
    try:
        print("Ticker symbol: ", mydict[given_input])
    except:
        print("False Input")

def symbol_to_name(mydict):
    given_input = input("Enter ticker: ")
    for key, value in mydict.items():
        if given_input == value:
            print("Company name: ", key)
            return
    print("False Input")
```

I hope this helped you out. If you want to know how it exactly works, you can let me know.
Also this search is case sensitiv. In the textfile you have quite a mess of uppercase and lowercase. Maybe address that if you want to simplify the use of your programm a bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
def tickers_to_dict():
    ticker_dict = {}
    bestand = open('pe_8_4_tickers.txt', 'r')
    tickers = bestand.readlines()
    for line in tickers:
        k, v = line.split(':')
        ticker_dict[k] = v
    return (ticker_dict)

def name_to_symbol(mydict):
    given_input = input("Enter company name: ")
    for key, value in mydict.items():
        if given_input == key:
            print("Ticker symbol:", value)
            return
    else:
    #     print("Ticker symbol: )
    # except:
        print("False Input")

def symbol_to_name(mydict):
    given_input = input("Enter ticker symbol: ")
    for key, value in mydict.items():
        if given_input == value:
            print("Ticker symbol:", key)
            return
    else:
        print("False Input")

name_to_symbol(tickers_to_dict())

symbol_to_name(tickers_to_dict())
```

Athos it didnt work

second def statement returns with false input